# iOS/Swift: Trying to add protocol methods to a UIView's buttons tell me that my methods aren't exposed to objective C

Tags: ios, swift

I'm working on a comic viewer. I want to have a view that doesn't know anything about the data and is dumb and uses a delegate. I want a view controller to use the view and bind the data with it. The controller will conform to the protocol. Here is my attempt.

Here's my protocol:

```
import Foundation

protocol ComicViewDelegate {
    var comic: XKCDComic? {get set}
    func handleMostRecentClicked()
    func handlePrevClicked()
    func handleNextClicked()
    func handleRandomClicked()
    func handleSelectedComicNumber(of number: Int)
}
```

Here's my view:

```
class ComicView: UIView {

    var delegate: ComicViewDelegate?

    public lazy var view = UIView()

    public lazy var mostRecentButton: UIButton = {
        let button = UIButton()
        button.addTarget(self, action: #selector(delegate?.handleMostRecentClicked), for: .touchUpInside)

        view.addSubview(button)
        return button
    }()

    ...
}
```

Problems:

1. I get `"Argument of '#selector' refers to instance method 'handleMostRecentClicked()' that is not exposed to Objective-C"` for all methods.
2. If I add `@objc` before `protocol ComicViewDelegate`, my `handleSelectedComicNumber` method gets `"Argument of '#selector' does not refer to an '@objc' method, property, or initializer"` when I try to pass in a parameter, and also..
3. `XKCDComic` is a struct that is `Decodable` so I can't make it an NSObject

Any tips on this?

Answer (score 1):

The problem is here ( button event searches for the selector inside the target which is the instance of the view , so method should be written inside it )

```
button.addTarget(self, action: #selector(delegate?.handleMostRecentClicked), for: .touchUpInside)
```

change to

```
button.addTarget(self, action: #selector(self.handleMostRecentClicked(_:)), for: .touchUpInside)
```

//

```
 @objc func handleMostRecentClicked (_ sender:UIButton) {

  delegate?.handleMostRecentClicked()
}
```